# Getting lost understanding the role of this callback function (BFS, width level for trees)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, callback, tree, breadth-first-search

I'm currently working with and learning trees and have been dealing with different implementations of traversals.

```
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
      this.data = data;
      this.children = [];
  }

  add(data) {
      this.children.push(new Node(data));
  }

  remove(data) {
      this.children = this.children.filter(node => {
          return node.data !== data;
      })
  }
}

traverseBF(fn) {
    const arr = [this.root];
    while (arr.length) {
        const node = arr.shift();
        arr.push(...node.children);
        fn(node); //what role does this play?
    }
    return count;
}

traverseDF(fn) {
    const arr = [this.root]; 
    while (arr.length) {  
        const node = arr.shift(); 
        arr.unshift(...node.children); 
        fn(node); //what role does this play???
    }
}
```

I thought I had come to understand that the callback has the context where it's declared in and is able to access variables in the outer function and what I thought was the reason why arr stays up to date and that the callback function was integral for BFS/DFS to work in this instance. However, learning about calculating width levels broke my understanding.

```
function levelWidth(root) {
  const arr = [root, 's'];
  const counters = [0];

  while (arr.length > 1) {
      const node = arr.shift();

      if (node === 's') {
          counters.push(0);
          arr.push('s');
      } else {
          arr.push(...node.children);
          counters[counters.length - 1]++;
      }
  }
  return counters;
}
```

There's no callback here yet this BFS search and the traversal works fine. Can anyone help me understand better why it was needed in the first instance and not this instance??

What exactly happens when I call the traversal like so?

```
const letters = [];
const t = new Tree();
t.root = new Node('a');
t.root.add('b');
t.root.add('d');
t.root.children[0].add('c');
t.root.children[1].add('e');

t.traverseBF(node => {
    letters.push(node.data);
});
console.log(letters);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wrong or right here.

The callback version differs in two ways:

- It does not apply any logic using the visited nodes. It only takes care of the traversal, not of any other logic. Any specific logic is left to the caller who can pass a callback exactly for that purpose. In your final example, that specific logic consists of collecting the node's `data` values into an array. But note that the traversal function is unaware of this logic, which is a nice separation of concern.

  NB: the `return count` at the end of `traverseBF(fn)` should not be there (there is no `count`)
- It does not keep the caller waiting until *all* nodes are visited.

The non-callback version, not only visits the nodes, but also takes care of a *specific* processing on those nodes (i.e some counting), and it returns the result of that processing only. This is much less generic. If you want a traversal for a completely different purpose, you cannot use this function, as it really does not tell the caller about the nodes it has visited, nor the order in which this happened.

You could also imagine a kind of "in-between" traversal implementation: one that does not use a callback, but just collects all the visited nodes in an array, and then returns that complete array of nodes in the order that they were visited. This is more generic, but the caller must *wait* until all nodes have been visited before it can start applying its own algorithm on that returned array of nodes.

So, I would say the callback version is more flexible and generic.

However, the more modern way to implement such a generic traversal is not via a callback system, but as a *generator*.

Here is how that would look (notice the initial `*`)

```
* traverseBF() {
    const arr = [this.root];
    while (arr.length) {
        const node = arr.shift();
        arr.push(...node.children);
        yield node;  // <---
    }
}

* traverseDF() {
    const arr = [this.root]; 
    while (arr.length) {  
        const node = arr.shift(); 
        arr.unshift(...node.children); 
        yield node; // <---
    }
}
```

The caller must be aware of the fact that these methods are generators, but you can use a for loop like this:

```
let letters = [];
for (let node of t.traverseDF()) {
    // do something with this node before continuing the traversal
    letters.push(node.data);
}
console.log(letters);
```

The additional advantage here is that the caller can always decide to discontinue the traversal. In the above code, an early `break` from the loop would really mean that the traversal would not be completed any further. For all the other methods mentioned earlier, you would have to trigger an exception to make that possible; in all other cases the traversal would have to run until completion.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful.